# Enable Kotlin typealias type check with annotations

Tags: java, class, kotlin, annotations, type-alias

Kotlin has typealiases that are really handy where you want to have a good naming. However, there are some occasions where you want to have a typealias that is a little more that just an alias, you want it to enforce an actual compile time check, without the need of creating a new class.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
typealias MyNum = Int

fun isMagical(num: MyNum) = num == 42

fun main() {
    // Should fail/warn
    isMagical(42)
    // Should pass
    isMagical(42 as MyNum)

    // Should fail/warn
    val x = 3
    isMagical(x)

    // Should pass
    val y: MyNum = 3
    isMagical(y)
}
```

I know that I could use an inline class to achieve that, but I need many of these types check and don't want to create a class for each of them.

Is it possible to that with an annotation? Like:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPEALIAS)
annotation class StrongType

@StrongType
typealias MyNum = Int
```

and then have an annotation processor doing the check?

I would like to do something similar to Android `@IntDef`:

```
// Android way (performant but needs to manually annotates methods and list the options in the annotation)
@Retention(SOURCE)
@IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
public @interface NavigationMode {}
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;
```

```
// Enum way (not performant)
enum class NavMode constructor(val value: Int){
    STANDARD(0),
    LIST(1),
    TABS(2)
}

// Inline class (performant but generating a lot of code)
inline class NavMode(val value: Int) {
    companion object {
        val STANDARD = NavMode(0)
        val LIST = NavMode(1)
        val TABS = NavMode(2)
    }
}

// This is what I would like: performant, type check in methods without annotating them, clean code
@StrongType
typealias NavMode = Int
const val STANDARD: NavMode = 0
const val LIST: NavMode = 1
const val TABS: NavMode = 2
```

Please notice that this is not my real use case, I have lots of such enums to create while remaining performant (just like in android APIs).
What do you think it's the most viable way to achieve what I want?
Thanks

Comment: Probably not the response you are looking for, but perhaps the way you are modelling your data might be the issue.  If your need to do the `isMagical` check often it sounds to me like you require a type as the check can be part of the type.  If only certain values are "special" then perhaps an enum would be a better fit.  Just a thought.

Comment: I have efficiency constraints and lots of such enums to create, it's not really a suitable solution for me

Answer (score 3):

`typealias MyNum = Int` means that `MyNum` is another name for `Int`, that's pretty much it. Your "should warn" checks don't work because a `MyNum` is an `Int` and an `Int` is a `MyNum` - there's no difference between the two as far as the type system is concerned.

If you want the type system to consider them as separate things, then you actually need a separate type, and you'll run into issues if you just want a "special Int" because `Int` is a final class, you can't subclass it unfortunately. So you wouldn't just be able to treat `MyInt` as an `Int`.

---

Your examples with the IntDefs, enums etc are a bit different - there you definitely want a new type, with a limited set of possible, pre-defined values. Some languages would allow you to do this and still treat it as an `Int` - Kotlin doesn't though.

IntDefs are probably the closest to what you want, where you have to annotate everything because that's how it's being checked - it's outside of the type system. It's unwieldy but that's because it's bolted on.

Sealed classes can get you the kind of "clean" definition you want:

```
// or an interface
abstract class MyInt() {
    abstract val value: Int
}

// put them inside the sealed class (in {}) if you want them named NavMode.LIST etc
sealed class NavMode(override val value: Int) : MyInt()
object STANDARD : NavMode(0)
object LIST : NavMode(1)
object TABS : NavMode(2)
```

but this is basically an enum without the enumeration (which you can take advantage of to ensure that each value is unique - there's no checking here, you could pass 0 for every value)

---

You said you have "efficiency constraints", but do you? Like, would having one instance of each enum in memory *actually* be a problem, or holding references to objects instead of primitives? IntDefs are (were? you don't hear much about it these days...) the recommended way to avoid those object allocations and references, but it's a tradeoff with way more complex code.

Enums are simple, and sometimes that's more important. I'd recommend doing some profiling and see how much of an impact using them would actually be, before you throw out what's probably the best solution. Just worth thinking about!

Answer (score 0):

Annotation processors can't change the way compiler does his job. They can only generate new source code files (and give them to the compiler).
You can make annotation processor to generate inline class from annotated typealias (`inline class MyNum(val v: Int)`), but it's not enough. You also need to replace all `Int` to `MyInt` type casts with actual `MyInt` instances creation (`42 as MyNum` should become `MyNum(42)`) and all their usages with property access: (`num == 42` should become `num.v == 42`).

And that's impossible, because:

1. Reflection API doesn't provide access to local variables of type (unless you explicitly marked them with some annotations too).
2. Annotation processors can’t modify existing files, they can only create new ones (by the way, typealias will be there too and will collide with generated inline class)

Probably it could be done with compiler plugin, but currently ["Kotlin compiler plugins API is extremely experimental and is under heavy development"](https://twitter.com/relizarov/status/1387833904124596225)